# Group By List with Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a simple object:

```
public class obj
    {
        public Int32 id { get; set; }

        public Int32 source { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a list: `List<obj>` of 10 objects, 5 of them have source set to `100`, 3 have source set to `200` and 2 have source set to `2500`

I need to group by the source which will result in three items `100`, `200` and `2500`.
Also I need to order by count, like this:

```
5 100
3 200 
2 2500
```

The end result is that I want to get the source with the top count, which in this case will be `100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you source with top count:

```
int topSource = list.GroupBy(o => o.source)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                    .First()
                    .Key;
```

Explanation

- Group items by source value (it will create three groups)
- Order groups by items count in each group
- Select first group (it will have max items count)
- Get grouping key (which is source value)

Answer (score 3):

```
var res = lst.GroupBy(o=>o.source)
             .Select(grp=>new {Count=grp.Count(),Source=grp.Key});
```