# Groupby Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a class like mentioned below:

```
   public class journey
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have an object.

```
List<Journey> jouneyList = new List<Journey>();
```

I want to groupby this list based on from and to properties and have it in a list. how to do it?

Comment: Thats nice, so whats the question, which part are you having trouble with, which questions have you looked at, and what didn't work for you

Comment: What do you want to do with the groups once you've got them ?

Comment: @Saruman I had checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553437/group-by-list-with-lambda

Comment: @bommelding  there is a method which returns different configured value for for each unique from and to combination. I have to fetch that value.

Comment: In that case you will need a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<IEnumerable<journey>> result = jouneyList.GroupBy(x=> new {  x.From, x.To }).ToList();
```